# How to download apk within phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, apk

We are developing a PhoneGap app and want to provide a link to the new apk file when a new version is available.

eg:

```
<a href="http://myserver.com/myapp.apk">Download</a>
```

It is an in-house app so we cannot put it on the android market. It worked fine with PhoneGap 1.5, but after an upgrade to version 1.9 it stopped working. If you click on the link nothing happens.

I've added our server to cordova.xml (`<access origin="http://myserver.com"/>`, also tried `<access origin="*"/>` ) and granded the permission INSTALL_PACKAGES in AndroidManifest.xml

Has anyone an idea what i am missing? Is it a permissions issue?

Comment: "and granded the permission INSTALL_PACKAGES in AndroidManifest.xml" -- Nope, you requested the INSTALL_PACKAGES permission and the System denied you. Normal applications cannot hold this permission. You must launch the Package installer and have the user press the install button in order to get an apk installed on a stock device. That wouldn't be the cause of your download trouble though, not sure what is up with that.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Any help would be great

Answer (score -1):

use this function for downloading file in phonegap

```
function downloadFile(){

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 

    function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(
        "dummy.html", {create: true, exclusive: false}, 
        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
            var sPath = fileEntry.fullPath.replace("dummy.html","");
            var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
            fileEntry.remove();

            fileTransfer.download(
                "http://www.w3.org/2011/web-apps-ws/papers/Nitobi.pdf",
                sPath + "theFile.pdf",
                function(theFile) {
                    console.log("download complete: " + theFile.toURI());
                    showLink(theFile.toURI());
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                    console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                    console.log("upload error code: " + error.code);
                }
            );
        }, fail);
    }, fail);
};
```

}